# Code inside the external repository

Tags: svn

I have a question that I'm searching for a proper answer for. I have seen too many similar questions but nothing to help me with my situation.
I have a project where there is a common code base. a code base with some configuration files to say. This code is stored in main trunk of the repo and branches are handled in main branch directories.
Then I have too many projects that are using this code base with some changes in configuration files or with some added files INSIDE the code base's directories. I want to keep the code base in common so if any body changes anything inside a project which is related to the code base it will be commited back to the main code but also I want to keep the projects' specific files separated so that as obvious no one will overwrite configs of others or no one has to carry others' additional files within his code.

As I searched for possible answer to my problem, I came to externals, so now I have this structure in my repo:

```
/
    trunk    <- code base trunk
    branch   <- code base branchs
    projects
        proj1
            trunk    <- project's trunk
            branch   <- project's branches
        proj2
```

the trunk of each project is actually an external link to code base's trunk and I have made some changes inside the folders or changed some config files. now I have no way to separate some changes made to code to be sobmitted to proj1's folder and others to the main code.
is it at all possible? should I change my structure?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this layout:

```
/
    common
        trunk    <- code base trunk
        branches   <- code base branches
    projects
        proj1
            trunk    <- project's trunk
               common  <- common trunk (external)
               local   <- proj1 specific
            branch   <- project's branches
               common  <- common branch (or trunk) (external)
               local   <- proj1 specific
        proj2
```

So, as you see, it's better divide project into common/specific parts.

**UPDATE** (in case splitting code base is not possible)

```
    trunk    <- code base trunk
      common.h
      common.c
      common_folder
    branches   <- code base branches
         br1
            common.h
            common.c
            common_folder
    projects
        proj1
            trunk    <- project's trunk
               common.h  <- (svn:externals ^/trunk/common.h common.h)
               common.c  <- (svn:externals ^/trunk/common.c common.c)
               common  <- (svn:externals ^/trunk/common_folder common)
               spec.h  
               spec.c 
            branches   <- project's branches
               br1
                 common.h  <- (svn:externals ^/branches/br1/common.h common.h)
                 common.c  <- (svn:externals ^/branches/br1/common.c common.c)
                 common  <- (svn:externals ^/branches/br1/common_folder common)
                 spec.h  
                 spec.c 
        proj2
```

In this case things become a bit complicated to manage...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but as I'm working with a already written code and a framework it is not possible to separate the code base and the config/specialized parts.

Comment: Then, you can extern a common files by adding "externals on files" - in that case you shouldn't separate code base, you only get files you need, and add project specific files into projX. You can also have files in projX with the same name as in code base which are different - but this will be messy, to my mind.

Comment: Thanks, any way I have too many files in common code that it is impossible to define external for each and I have also some files from common code base that has to be changed in each project, actually I have decided to use one branch for each project, this way I can update common code base and later update each branch, also each branch can have its own version of file if necessary.

Comment: Of course, having too many externals on files is not a good solution, but I am doubt also that having several branches for different projects can be good solution either (merging hell). You should really restructure your project to have one single configurable (runtime/compile-time) common code base.